# How to get reverse number code from letters?

Tags: php, encoding, decode, encode, decoding

I have function which encoding numbers to string like:

- 0 -> a
- 1 -> b
- 2 -> c
- ...
- 45 -> R

Function:

```
public static function encode($number) {
    $out = "";
    $codes = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    while ($number > 53) {
        $key = $number % 54;
        $number = floor($number / 54) - 1;
        $out = $codes{$key}.$out;
    }

    return $codes{$number}.$out;
}
```

How to make reverse function which will convert letters back to number?

Comment: You should take a look at strpos function which give you position of a lettre in string :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: reinventing ASCII table?

Comment: Based on your code, what does it mean by if the given number is greater than 53?

Comment: i would jsut build a simple array

Comment: @Dagon: Already a simple array called a string ;-)

Comment: its php, string=array=int=float=vogon poetry

Answer (score 2):

You can treat a string like an array and use the position, so this would be easier to encode:

```
$codes = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
return $codes[$number];
```

You may want some error checking like:

```
return isset($codes[$number]) ? $codes[$number] : false;
```

Then to decode, find the letter at that position:

```
$codes = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
return strpos($codes, $letter);
```

`strpos()` will return `false` for you if not found.

Comment: No one answer work. For example, I want to decode Hk4n, Za, www... It will always return 53

Comment: Then you need to edit your question with inputs and outputs.  That is not apparent from your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Its easy to use the `strpos` function

```
public static function decode($letter) {

    $letter = $letter[0];

    $codes = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    $pos = strpos($codes,$letter);

    return $pos;

}
```

Comment: No one answer work. For example, I want to decode Hk4n, Za, www... It will always return 53